# Upgrading from Font Awesome 4.1 to 4.2 - icons appear as boxes

Tags: font-awesome, font-awesome-4

I'm running a simple website that uses Font Awesome icons under 4.1

I'm keen to upgrade to 4.2 ad thought it was just a matter of copying the contents of the 4.2 min.css file into the existing 4.1 min.css file on my server but this has resulted in all the icons appearing as empty boxes.

What could I be doing wrong please?

Comment: I upgraded from 4.1 to 4.2.2 (font-awesome-sass) and have the same issue as you.

Comment: **[This](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/issues/45)** was my problem. I'm using the sass gem, but check that the url for the font files is the same as the actual location the font files are located.

Comment: Thanks so much - it was the path to the faults that was causing the problem - never thought to check that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user Lyrical!
Similar set up to you but having checked the location of the font files I found them in a different location. Quick shuffle of files later and everything is fine!

Answer (score 0):

This could be a stupid answer but are you using the correct format for the icons. ie. the extra 'fa'

```
<i class="fa fa-camera-retro fa-lg"></i>
```

Comment: Not a stupid answer at all! But, no unfortunately that's not the issue.